# How to swap rows in 2 pandas dataframes which contain lists and have different size?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, swap

I have two Pandas dataframes, df1 and df2. Each dataframe has one column named 'Path'. Each row has a list. They are like this:

df1

```
Path
[OAK, ORD, FLL, PBG]
[OAK, SEA, FLL, PBG]
[OAK, AUS, FLL, PBG]
[OAK, LAS, FLL, PBG]
[OAK, LAX, FLL, PBG]
[OAK, DAL, FLL, PBG]
[OAK, MDW, FLL, PBG]
[OAK, BWI, FLL, PBG]
```

The df1 constructor is:

```
{'Path': {0: ['OAK', 'ORD', 'FLL', 'PBG'],   2: ['OAK', 'SEA', 'FLL', 'PBG'],   4: ['OAK', 'AUS', 'FLL', 'PBG'],   6: ['OAK', 'LAS', 'FLL', 'PBG'],   8: ['OAK', 'LAX', 'FLL', 'PBG'],   10: ['OAK', 'DAL', 'FLL', 'PBG'],   12: ['OAK', 'MDW', 'FLL', 'PBG'],   14: ['OAK', 'BWI', 'FLL', 'PBG']}}
```

df2

```
Path
[OAK, DFW, FLL, PBG]
[OAK, JFK, FLL, PBG]
[OAK, MCI, FLL, PBG]
[OAK, PHX, FLL, PBG]
[OAK, DEN, FLL, PBG]
[OAK, HOU, FLL, PBG]
[OAK, ATL, FLL, PBG]
```

The df2 constructor is:

```
{'Path': {1: ['OAK', 'DFW', 'FLL', 'PBG'], 3: ['OAK', 'JFK', 'FLL', 'PBG'], 5: ['OAK', 'MCI', 'FLL', 'PBG'], 7: ['OAK', 'PHX', 'FLL', 'PBG'], 9: ['OAK', 'DEN', 'FLL', 'PBG'], 11: ['OAK', 'HOU', 'FLL', 'PBG'], 13: ['OAK', 'ATL', 'FLL', 'PBG']}}
```

One problem is that I have a different number of rows in my dataframes. I would like to swap the second element of each row of df1 with the second element of each row of df2. If there is no corresponding row, the row should not be modified or dropped. The desired output is:

df1

```
Path
[OAK, DFW, FLL, PBG]
[OAK, JFK, FLL, PBG]
[OAK, MCI, FLL, PBG]
[OAK, PHX, FLL, PBG]
[OAK, DEN, FLL, PBG]
[OAK, HOU, FLL, PBG]
[OAK, ATL, FLL, PBG]
[OAK, BWI, FLL, PBG]
```

df2

```
Path
[OAK, ORD, FLL, PBG]
[OAK, SEA, FLL, PBG]
[OAK, AUS, FLL, PBG]
[OAK, LAS, FLL, PBG]
[OAK, LAX, FLL, PBG]
[OAK, DAL, FLL, PBG]
[OAK, MDW, FLL, PBG]
```

How can I do it in Python?

Comment: if possible post the dataframe constructor code for the df1 and df2. `df1.to_dict()` and `df2.dict()` should work. This would make the work easy for the contributors to replicate the dataframes

Comment: you mean like this? df1 {'Path': {0: ['OAK', 'ORD', 'FLL', 'PBG'],
  2: ['OAK', 'SEA', 'FLL', 'PBG'],
  4: ['OAK', 'AUS', 'FLL', 'PBG'],
  6: ['OAK', 'LAS', 'FLL', 'PBG'],
  8: ['OAK', 'LAX', 'FLL', 'PBG'],
  10: ['OAK', 'DAL', 'FLL', 'PBG'],
  12: ['OAK', 'MDW', 'FLL', 'PBG'],
  14: ['OAK', 'BWI', 'FLL', 'PBG']}} df2 {'Path': {1: ['OAK', 'DFW', 'FLL', 'PBG'],
  3: ['OAK', 'JFK', 'FLL', 'PBG'],
  5: ['OAK', 'MCI', 'FLL', 'PBG'],
  7: ['OAK', 'PHX', 'FLL', 'PBG'],
  9: ['OAK', 'DEN', 'FLL', 'PBG'],
  11: ['OAK', 'HOU', 'FLL', 'PBG'], 
  13: ['OAK', 'ATL', 'FLL', 'PBG']}}

Comment: yes, please update the question with the dictionaries which can be used to create a dataframe using `pd.DataFrame()`

Comment: @anky_91 You can copy the table and use `pd.read_clipboard()` to get the dataframe

Comment: @abhilb thanks, but there is no list after doing it and you cant apply `literal_eval` without appending quotes. if i am not wrong. that sounds like too much work ;)

Comment: @anky_91 understood.

Comment: I have updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`combine_first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) here after converting the series of list into a dataframe:

```
n=pd.DataFrame(df2['Path'].tolist())
m=pd.DataFrame(df1['Path'].tolist())
#----------------------------------------------------
df1_final=n[[1]].combine_first(m).dropna().agg(list,1)
df2_final=m[[1]].combine_first(n).dropna().agg(list,1)
```

---

```
print(df1_final)
print('\n')
print(df2_final)

0    [OAK, DFW, FLL, PBG]
1    [OAK, JFK, FLL, PBG]
2    [OAK, MCI, FLL, PBG]
3    [OAK, PHX, FLL, PBG]
4    [OAK, DEN, FLL, PBG]
5    [OAK, HOU, FLL, PBG]
6    [OAK, ATL, FLL, PBG]
7    [OAK, BWI, FLL, PBG]
dtype: object


0    [OAK, ORD, FLL, PBG]
1    [OAK, SEA, FLL, PBG]
2    [OAK, AUS, FLL, PBG]
3    [OAK, LAS, FLL, PBG]
4    [OAK, LAX, FLL, PBG]
5    [OAK, DAL, FLL, PBG]
6    [OAK, MDW, FLL, PBG]
dtype: object
```